# html2canvas causes IE11 to hang and enter "Not responding" state

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, jspdf, html2canvas

This works great in Firefox and Chrome; however, in internet explorer 11 the process takes a very long time and results in the browser reporting not responding. If the user waits enough (anywhere from 30s-2 minutes) the process resolves.

I am trying to capture a PNG of a portion of the DOM using html2canvas and afterwards convert the PNG to PDF via jsPDF. Essentially I have elements with IDs that correspond to a page. I capture the page in a PNG, then expand the PNG to a full page in the PDF conversion step by adding each PNG as a page to the PDF. My code for doing so is shown below:

```
// Default to GMSRD1
        var fileName = "record-of-discussion-form.pdf";
        var pages = ["GMSRD1_page1", "GMSRD1_page2", "GMSRD1_page3", "GMSRD1_page4"]

        if (this.state.parsed.formId === "GMSC1") {
            fileName = "consultee-form.pdf"
            pages = ["GMSC1_page1", "GMSC1_page2", "GMSC1_page3"];
        }
        if (this.state.parsed.formId === "GMSA1") {
            fileName = "assent-form.pdf"
            pages = ["GMSA1_page1", "GMSA1_page2"];
        }
        if (this.state.parsed.formId === "GMSW2" ) {
            fileName = "withdraw-form.pdf"
            pages = ["GMSW2_page1", "GMSW2_page2", "GMSW2_page3"];
        }

        // Objct to build 
        var pdf = new jsPDF({
            orientation: "p",
            unit: "pt",
            format: "a4",
            compression: true
        });

        // Canvas creation promises
        let promises = [];

        // Capture canvas for each page 
        pages.forEach(page => {
            let element = document.getElementById(page);
            promises.push(this.getCanvasData(element));
        });

        Promise.all(promises).then(dataUrls => {
            dataUrls.forEach((dataUrl, i) => {
                pdf.addImage(dataUrl, "PNG", 45, 40, 800 * .63, 980 * .7, undefined, "FAST");

                pdf.addPage();
            });

            let testOutput = pdf.output('arraybuffer'); // arraybuffer 
            var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(testOutput);
            var array = Array.from(uint8Array)

            // <DO something w/ data below>
```

Has anyone seen this behavior or have any workarounds? Wondering if there is there a way to release the current state of the process to the browser via timeouts to avoid this behavior?

Edit: I've got an open issue on the library addressing the problem as well (see comments)

Comment: Can I ask why this needs to work in IE at all, rather than in Edge? (you might have a solid reason, but you might also be trying to solve for a browser that is basically irrelevant, given Edge, and windows 7 hitting true EOL half a year from now)

Comment: I hate IE. Don’t get me wrong. It’s a client requirement :(

Comment: "I'm getting paid to make it work" is basically the only true reason =) Having said that, html2canvas is an open source project on github, so if you haven't asked this on https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues yet, you should probably do that (both because posting to SO implies you exhausted your options, which won't be true if you've not asked on their issue tracker yet, but also because 2 minutes vs. a few seconds likes like quite the bug the html2canvas folks would want to know about, too).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans already done ;) ... was hoping to ask the same here in an effort to get more visibility https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1889

Comment: always good to mention in your post when you have, because the best place for an answer is not here. It's in the html2canvas codebase and documentation =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans noted! I've updated the post

Answer (score 0):

have you try to clean up cache n/or history? similar happens to me sometimes with chrome, and that seems to works for me

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use [ignoreElements](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration) attribute to ignore the unnecessary elements to improve the convent performance. please check [this thread](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1731) and [this link](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/126).

Comment: Hmm... this could be a thought, though I'm getting each element that is a page, which effectively has all the content I want. I'm not sure if I could remove elements from these pages.